# How to show that $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3+\cdots\sqrt{2006}}}}<2$

Tags: inequality, nested-radicals

$\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3+\cdots\sqrt{2006}}}}<2$.
I struggled on it, but I didn't find any pattern to solve it.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: Does anyone know the limit of $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3+\cdots +\sqrt{n}}}}$ in closed form?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NestedRadicalConstant.html?affilliate=1

Comment: @OlayinkaSF, thanks for the link!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

$$\begin{aligned}\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3+\cdots \sqrt{n}}}}&<\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2^2+\cdots \sqrt{2^{2^{n-1}}}}}}\\&<\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2^2+\cdots }}}\\&=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}\cdot\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\cdots }}}\\&=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}\phi}\\&<2\end{aligned}$$

---

We can get a tighter bound for the limit by breaking the pattern a little further down the line:

$$\begin{aligned}\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3+\cdots \sqrt{n}}}}&<\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3+\sqrt{2^2+\cdots}}}}\\&=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3+2\sqrt{1+\cdots }}}}\\&=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{4+\sqrt{5}}}}\approx 1.7665398\end{aligned}$$

$$\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3+\cdots }}}\approx 1.7579327$$

Comment: Very nice. And a pretty good bound too, because the limit seems to be $1.757932756618\ldots$ and $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}\phi} \approx 1.813352037325$. Does anyone know this limit in closed form?

Comment: In $2^{2^n}$, is there a power too much?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NestedRadicalConstant.html?affilliate=1

Answer (score 17):

Idea: You can unwrap like this:

$$\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3+\cdots+\sqrt{2006}}}}<2$$

if

$$\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3+\cdots+\sqrt{2006}}}<2^2-1$$

if

$$\sqrt{3+\cdots+\sqrt{2006}}<(2^2-1)^2-2$$

and so on, so we want to show

$$2006 < (((2^2-1)^2-2)^2-\cdots)^2-2005$$

---

might as well prove it by induction for all $n$ rather than just 2006, so we need to show that

$$n+1 < (((2^2-1)^2-2)^2-\cdots)^2-n$$

implies

$$n+2 < ((((2^2-1)^2-2)^2-\cdots)^2-n)^2-(n+1)$$

but thats just

$$2n+3 < ((((2^2-1)^2-2)^2-\cdots)^2-n)^2$$

which holds since

$$2n+3 < (n+1)^2$$

for all $n>1$.

Answer (score 1):

I got a nice one! ($46^2=2116)$

$\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3+\sqrt{4+....+2016}}}}<\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3+\sqrt{46^2}}}}=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{49}}}=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{9}}=2.$