# What is the limit of $\lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty }{ \sum _{ k=1 }^{ n }{ { k }^{ \left( \frac { 1 }{ 2k } \right) } } } $

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

When I was trying to solve this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/404653/how-to-show-that-sqrt1-sqrt2-sqrt3-cdots-sqrt20062)

I came up to this: $$\lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty  }{ \sum _{ k=1 }^{ n }{ { k }^{ \left( \frac { 1 }{ 2k }  \right)  } }  } ={ 1 }^{ 1/2 }+{ 2 }^{ 1/4 }+{ 3 }^{ 1/6 }+...+{ n }^{ 1/(2n) }.$$Does it converge? What is the limit of the sum?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has no limit since $k^{\frac{1}{2k}}\to 1$ and $k\to\infty$.

You don't really need that to see that it can't converge, since $k^{\frac{1}{2k}}>1$ for all $k$.

Comment: Or this has limit $+\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_n \sqrt[2n]{n} =1 \neq 0$$

thus the series diverges.